# Python: How can I access an mp3 file's metadata using Python?

Tags: python, file-io, metadata

Supposing I wanted to see the Artist Name? Or add BPM information? What Python tools could I go about doing this?

Comment: For both: Windows and UNIX systems...

Comment: I don't think eyed3 is compatible with python 3.  It does support the bpm tag but not others like album artist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a module called [Python-ID3](http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/) that does exactly this. If you're on a Debian/Ubuntu box, its package name is `python-id3` and there is example code on its website:

```
from ID3 import *
try:
    id3info = ID3('/some/file/moxy.mp3')
    print id3info
    id3info['TITLE'] = "Green Eggs and Ham"
    id3info['ARTIST'] = "Moxy Früvous"
    for k, v in id3info.items():
        print k, ":", v
except InvalidTagError, message:
    print "Invalid ID3 tag:", message
```

Comment: wound up using eyed3, but thank you. Everyone.