# Change properties of an mp3 file in python

Tags: python

How to change the property of a file in python

I have an mp3 file which has properties like Title, Contributing Artists, Album.
How can I access these properties using python and change them

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164646/python-how-can-i-access-an-mp3-files-metadata-using-python?lq=1